# Powershell Flatten dir recursively

Tags: powershell

Found a couple of semi-related links:

[How to merge / 'flatten' a folder structure using PowerShell - recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57846927/how-to-merge-flatten-a-folder-structure-using-powershell-recursive)

but my ask is that I have a root dir P:/files

which has several layers of sub directories etc I'd like to flatten all of them so that all the -Files are moved just to the root of P:/files

I don't need to be concerned with duplicates as I'll make sure there are non well before this stage.

it looks like I can use powershell to get a list of all the files no matter the level, and then just for-each over them and a move?

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath P:\files -Directory | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File
```

help on the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single recursive [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) that pipes to [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) should do:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -LiteralPath P:\files |
  Move-Item -Destination $yourDestination -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

If you need to exclude files directly located in `P:\files`:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -LiteralPath P:\files | Get-ChildItem -File |
  Move-Item -Destination $yourDestination -WhatIf
```

Note the use of `-Directory` and `-Recurse` first, so that all subdirectories in the entire subtree are returned, followed by a *non-recursive* `Get-ChildItem -File` call that gets each subdirectory's immediate files only.